# Connect to a local ActiveMQ Artemis queue in JBoss EAP 7.3

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

We are creating ActiveMQ Artemis queues in JBoss EAP 7.3 and calling them from a remote application developed using Spring Boot. Till now, we are using the protocol `http-remoting` for connecting to a remote ActiveMQ Artemis and we are using the connecting factory as `jms/RemoteConnectionFactory`. These set of configurations are working correctly.

Now we will deploy the Spring Boot application in the same JBoss server in which the queues are created and we need to access the queues locally instead of remotely. For accessing the queues locally, we are changing the connection factory to `jms/ConnectionFactory`. Can anyone please suggest me what is the protocol that needs to be used for accessing the queues locally instead of `http-remoting`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing resources via JNDI in the same JVM you don't need to specify anything in your `InitialContext` properties. An empty `InitialContext` will be automatically populated with the necessary info to lookup local resources.

If you *must* configure JNDI properties for some reason then you can simply set `java.naming.factory.initial` to `org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory`. Nothing else is needed.

Comment: We are reading the properties from a properties file in a Spring bean. For accessing the remote queue, we were providing the properties and we will have to use the same code because we want to make the code reusable for accessing local as well as remote queues. So we will have to provide the information in properties file. So it would be better if I knew the default values

Comment: Why not simply check for the existence of the JNDI properties and if they don't exist then simply do `new InitialContext()` (i.e. with no properties) in your application?

Comment: Actually I will not be able to modify the code since it will also be used for connecting to remote queues

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying. What if a particular JNDI property doesn't exist in you properties file? You will get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I will paste the spring XML used for creating the bean and will modify the question to include few more details, please give me a day. Will reopen a new thread if required